# Массив массивов вывести в таблицу циклом

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Хотелось бы несколько массивов, находящихся в общем массиве, вывести в однострочную таблицу с помощью цикла, отрисовывающего разметку такой таблицы. Каждый элемент (массив) должен быть в своей ячейке таблицы, а ячейки выстроены в строку таблицы.
Однако страница ожидаемо выдает "Notice: Array to string conversion.." Не хотелось бы рисовать всю таблицу отдельными тегами. Есть ли какой красивый способ решить вопрос с помощью цикла?

Пример, который работает для примитивных переменных:

```
//  $tdRC = заранее сформированный массив переменных;
//  $cols = число переменных;
$table = '<table border = 1 style="border-collapse: collapse">';

for ($tr = 0; $tr < 1; $tr++) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for ($td = 0; $td < $cols; $td++) {
        $table .= '<td><pre>' . $tdRC[$td][$tr] . '</pre></td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Типичный пример одного из таких элементов общего массива:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [LastName] => LastName
            [FirstName] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 65465
                    [IDOriginal] => 65465
                    [LastName] => LastName
                    [FirstName] => Evgeniy
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 30419
                    [IDOriginal] => 30419
                    [LastName] => LastName2
                    [FirstName] => FirstName2
                )

        )

)
```

строка таблицы, нарисованной вручную для пяти элементов - массивов (присутствуют три из них), выглядит так: [image: строка таблицы для пяти элементов - массивов]

Comment: введите результат выполнения print_r($tdRC); Чтобы знать с какими данными вы работаете

Comment: @Вадим Александру пример элемента массива добавил в текст вопроса

Comment: Отлично, можете еще визуально отобразить что вы хотите получиить?

Comment: @Вадим Александру добавил картинку

Comment: @SimplyOne вас просили нарисовать, что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: @binliz заметил и нарисовал

Comment: $tdRC[$td][$tr] заменить на print_r($tdRC[$td][$tr],1)

Comment: похоже, работает. спасибо